# Solve the limit $\lim_{x\to 0+} x\int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t}dt$

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

Solve the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0+} ~ x\int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t}dt$.

$f$ is continuos on $[0,1]$.

I tried using mean value theorem (there exists $c\in[0,1] s.t ...) $to see where $\displaystyle\int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t}dt$ as $x\to 0+$ so I get the expression $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{f(t)}{t}dt=f(c)\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{t}$ and then solve the improper integral, which diverges.

I'm not sure if I can apply that theorem, nor how to approach this initial limit.

Comment: Did you know $f(t)$ in the first hand...?

Comment: $f$ is continuos on $[0,1]$, and no.

Comment: Suggestion: First figure out what happens when $f$ is constant. Then, since $f$ is continuous, it's roughly equal to $f(0)$ near $0$, which is where your integrand is getting large.

Comment: By parts make the integral becomes $0$, but probably is not a good way to go.

Comment: Oh btw the mean value theorem only works when $f(t)$ is d-able.

Comment: Yeah, i'll try doing parts, but I don't think I'll get to something.

Comment: I was also in doubt with using the mean value theorem.

Comment: Use L'Hospital's Rule and get $0$ as answer. Write the expression under limit as $\dfrac{\int_x^1 (f(t) /t) \, dt} {1/x}$.

Comment: You should also note that L'Hospital's Rule gives more information. If $xf(x) \to L$ as $x\to 0^+$ then the limit in question is $L$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh - In this case $f$ is specified to be continuous as $0$, so that can't happen, but it is a nice observation for a wider class of functions.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: well for current question $f$ is continuous at $0$ so $xf(x) \to 0$ and hence the desired limit is $0$.

Comment: Thanks, great way to do it too.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh- You're right! I keep thinking $0$ needs to be handled as a special case for this problem, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous, it is a bounded function on $[0;1]$. Let
$$m \le f(x) \le M$$
Then
$$x \int_x^1 \frac{m}{t} \mathrm dt \le x \int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t} \mathrm dt \le x \int_x^1 \frac{M}{t} \mathrm dt$$
But now
$$x \int_x^1 \frac{m}{t} \mathrm dt = - m x \log x \to 0$$ as $x \to 0$. Similarly you can prove that
$$x \int_x^1 \frac{M}{t} \mathrm dt = - M x \log x \to 0$$
Hence by the squeeze theorem the limit is zero.

Answer (score 3):

Just to give another approach, note that if $\int_0^1{f(t)\over t}dt$ converges, then the requested limit is clearly $0$, while if it tends to $\pm\infty$, then L'Hopital and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tell us that

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}x\int_x^1{f(t)\over t}\,dt=\lim_{x\to0^+}{\int_x^1{f(t)\over t}\,dt\over1/x}=\lim_{x\to0^+}{-f(x)/x\over-1/x^2}=\lim_{x\to0^+}xf(x)=0\cdot f(0)=0$$